# Function latin2cyr or vice versa in c++ 

Tags: c++, string, stl

What is the easiest/optimal way to transform AnsiString into Cyrillic using C++ STL!

in php it would be

```
<?php
  // функция превода текста с кириллицы в траскрипт
  function encodestring($st)
  {
    // Сначала заменяем "односимвольные" фонемы.
    $st=strtr($st,"абвгдеёзийклмнопрстуфхъыэ_",
    "abvgdeeziyklmnoprstufh'iei");
    $st=strtr($st,"АБВГДЕЁЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЪЫЭ_",
    "ABVGDEEZIYKLMNOPRSTUFH'IEI");
    // Затем - "многосимвольные".
    $st=strtr($st, 
                    array(
                        "ж"=>"zh", "ц"=>"ts", "ч"=>"ch", "ш"=>"sh", 
                        "щ"=>"shch","ь"=>"", "ю"=>"yu", "я"=>"ya",
                        "Ж"=>"ZH", "Ц"=>"TS", "Ч"=>"CH", "Ш"=>"SH", 
                        "Щ"=>"SHCH","Ь"=>"", "Ю"=>"YU", "Я"=>"YA",
                        "ї"=>"i", "Ї"=>"Yi", "є"=>"ie", "Є"=>"Ye"
                        )
             );
    // Возвращаем результат.
    return $st;
  }
?>
```

I prefer to use STL Containers, need help!

Comment: Transform AnsiString into Cyrillic, meaning you want to implement the *inverse* of this `encodestring` function? (BTW, it's better if you provide the comments in English.)

Comment: I mean encoding String! e.g. `samiev`=`самиев`

Comment: OK. Because your `encodestring` performs the transformation `encodestring('самиев') === 'samiev'`.

Comment: In php it's easier 'cause it has an associative array, but in c++ it's a little bit different!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I wrote my own func and it works well! I think it'll get my job done but not so optimized! Tried to use map.find() smth like this but .....

```
AnsiString Latin2Cyr(AnsiString inStr)
{
    int l=inStr.Length();
    if (!l) return "";

    AnsiString strLat[]={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
    AnsiString strCyr[]={"а","б","с","д","е","ф","г","х","и","дж","к","л","м","н","о","п","к","р","с","т","у","в","у","кс","й","з"};
    AnsiString outStr="";
    typedef multimap<AnsiString,AnsiString> mmp;
    mmp mStr;
    int ln=(sizeof(strLat))/(sizeof(AnsiString));
    for (int i = 0; i < ln; i++) mStr.insert(mmp::value_type(strLat[i],strCyr[i]));
    AnsiString k=""; mmp::iterator it;
    for (int j = 1; j <l+1; j++) {
        for ( it=mStr.begin(); it!= mStr.end();++it ){
            outStr+=((*it).first==inStr.SubString(j,1))? (*it).second : k ;
        }
    }
    return outStr;
}
```

any ideas to optimize it?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the same code style in C++ also. Look to the std::map container. In newest standard C++11 you are also able to initialize it in a very convinient manner:

```
map letters = 
 {{ "f", "ф"},
  { "h", "х"},
  //and so on
 };
```